# How to get view name and display ID in template_preprocess_node function

Tags: views, 8, theming, nodes

I'm having some trouble in order to get a view's name and the display ID in a `template_preprocess_node function`.
I have a custom content type and a view with two different displays.
My idea is to define a variable in the preprocess function related to the content type (using `theme_preprocess__content_type_name` function), in order to use this variable in the Twig template to switch between the displays, according to the number of results.

I understand that in order to use a variable in the preprocess function, it has to be defined somehow in the template (correct me if I got this wrong).
So my question is: how can I call the view and the display in the node preprocess function?

EDIT 1:
Using Hudri suggestion:

```
function theme_name_preprocess_node__content_type(&$variables) {

    $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject();
    $view_id = $route->getDefault('view_id');
    $display_id = $route->getDefault('display_id');
    if($view_id == 'view_name' && $display_id == 'display_name'){
        $counter = count($view_id->result);
        $variables['count'] = $counter;
    }
}
```

Can the variable `count` be used in the Twig template in an if clause?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using a view page to display your content type:

```
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject();
$view_id = $route->getDefault('view_id');
$display_id = $route->getDefault('display_id');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm not using a view page, but a block called in the Twig template. I updated the  question, to be more specific.